# How to put something in the root directory of WAR using Maven?

Tags: java, maven, servlets, gwt, war

I'm trying to put a directory called `.ebextensions` in the root of my WAR using maven. I need this directory to be in the top level directory of my war, in the same place where my META-INF directory is.

I've tried putting `.ebextensions` in my `/src/main/resources` directory, and then compiled using `mvn install`, but this directory is not put in the war.

Am I doing anything wrong?

The project is using google web toolkit, if that makes any difference, but its a normal maven project in every sense (uses a .pom file, requires `mvn clean install` for compiling, etc).

Comment: Stuff in the /src/main/resources goes into the root of the classpath, not into the root of the war file.  There's probably a way to do it with other options in the maven war plugin, though.  If not, you may need to use maven assembly plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put it in the root by putting it in "src/main/webapp"

Comment: Why?  Will the WEB-INF folder do?

Comment: It's the standard directory layout, and web resources will be copied by default to the root of the WAR.

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html